# How to bind a button with a function using KV language

Tags: python, binding, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm trying to make a basic UI using KivyMD and Python (I'm a beginner), but I have some biding issues. If any of you could help me, I would be very gratefull. This is the error that my IDE returns to me:

File "C:\Users\kaua.silva\Desktop\app_ig\app.kv", line 67, in 
on_release: root.get_texts()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.**getattr**
AttributeError: 'FloatLayout' object has no attribute 'get_texts'

**main.py file:**

```
from kivymd.tools.hotreload.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

class App(MDApp):
    def get_texts(self):
        user_text_field = self.root.ids.username
        user_text_field = user_text_field.text

        password_text_field = self.root.ids.passoword
        password_text_field = password_text_field.text

        quantity_text_field = self.root.ids.quantity
        quantity_text_field = quantity_text_field.text

        return user_text_field, password_text_field, quantity_text_field

    KV_FILES = ["app.kv"]
    DEBUG = True
    def build_app(self):
        Window.size = (320, 370)
        Window.resizable = 0
        return Builder.load_file("app.kv")

App().run()
```

**app.kv file:**

```
FloatLayout: #:kivy !
    Image:
        source: "src/images/instagram_bg.jpg"
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
    MDLabel: 
        text: "Comment Bot"
        color: "#FFFFFF"
        font_size: "38sp"
        font_name: "font.ttf"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.59, "center_y": 0.9}
    MDIcon:
        icon: "instagram"
        color: "#FFFFFF"
        font_size: "45sp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.85, "center_y": 0.90}
    MDTextField:
        id: username
        line_color_normal: "#ffffff"
        line_color_focus: "#ffffff"
        hint_text: "Nome de usuário ou e-mail"
        size_hint_x: .8
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.75}
        mode: "rectangle"
        hint_text_color_normal: "white"
        hint_text_color_focus: "white"
        text_color_focus: "#ffffff"
        text_color_normal: "#ffffff"
        font_size: "20sp"
    MDTextField:
        id: password
        line_color_normal: "#ffffff"
        line_color_focus: "#ffffff"
        text_color: "#ffffff"
        hint_text: "Senha"
        size_hint_x: .8
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.57}
        mode: "rectangle"
        hint_text_color_normal: "white"
        hint_text_color_focus: "white"
        text_color_focus: "#ffffff"
        text_color_normal: "#ffffff"
        font_size: "20sp"
    MDTextField:
        id: quantity
        color_mode: "primary"
        line_color_normal: "#ffffff"
        line_color_focus: "#ffffff"
        hint_text: "Quantidade de comentários"
        size_hint_x: .8
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.39}
        mode: "rectangle"
        hint_text_color_normal: "white"
        hint_text_color_focus: "white"
        text_color_focus: "#ffffff"
        text_color_normal: "#ffffff"
        font_size: "20sp"
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Iniciar"
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: "#FFFFFF"
        font_style: "Button"
        md_bg_color: "#C8439C"
        size_hint: .5, .13
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .155}
        font_size: "16sp"
        on_release: root.get_texts()
```

I want to bind the function get_texts (it is just a simbolic function, that I'll replace for another) with the MDRaisedButton, but the vscode isn't recognizing the function. Thanks in advence!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following method code as bellow:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (320, 370)
        Window.resizable = 0
        return Builder.load_file("app.kv")

    def get_texts(self):
        user_text_field = self.root.ids.username
        user_text = user_text_field.text

        password_text_field = self.root.ids.password
        password_text = password_text_field.text

        quantity_text_field = self.root.ids.quantity
        quantity_text = quantity_text_field.text

        return user_text, password_text, quantity_text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

and I've changed the app.kv as bellow:

```
FloatLayout:
    Image:
        source: "src/images/instagram_bg.jpg"
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
    # add your other widgets here . . . (your other widgets)
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Iniciar"
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: "#FFFFFF"
        font_style: "Button"
        md_bg_color: "#C8439C"
        size_hint: .5, .13
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .155}
        font_size: "16sp"
        on_release: app.get_texts()
```

try that codes please.

Comment: Thank you very much!

The problem was resolved, but another little problem has emerged. Is there a way that I can use the hot reload app to see the modifications in real time, and also bind the function with the button using app.get_texts()?

Comment: To enable hot reloading in your KivyMD app and see modifications in real-time, follow these steps: Make sure you have the necessary dependencies installed. You need kivy, kivyMD, and pyjnius for hot reloading to work: pip install kivy kivymd pyjnius

Comment: Modify your main.py file to enable hot reloading:
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (320, 370)
        Window.resizable = 0
        return Builder.load_file("app.kv")

    def get_texts(self):
        user_text_field = self.root.ids.username
        user_text = user_text_field.text

Comment: password_text_field = self.root.ids.password
        password_text = password_text_field.text

        quantity_text_field = self.root.ids.quantity
        quantity_text = quantity_text_field.text

        return user_text, password_text, quantity_text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()

Comment: In your terminal, navigate to the directory containing your main.py and app.kv files.
Run your KivyMD app using the hot reload feature:
python -m main

Comment: Now, as you make modifications to your app.kv file, you should see those changes reflected in your running app without needing to restart it.

To bind the get_texts() function to the button using app.get_texts(), you can keep the on_release attribute as you have it in your app.kv file:

Comment: MDRaisedButton:
    text: "Iniciar"
    theme_text_color: "Custom"
    text_color: "#FFFFFF"
    font_style: "Button"
    md_bg_color: "#C8439C"
    size_hint: .5, .13
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .155}
    font_size: "16sp"
    on_release: app.get_texts()

Comment: MDRaisedButton:
    text: "Iniciar"
    theme_text_color: "Custom"
    text_color: "#FFFFFF"
    font_style: "Button"
    md_bg_color: "#C8439C"
    size_hint: .5, .13
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .155}
    font_size: "16sp"
    on_release: app.get_texts()

Comment: This way, when you click the button, it will call the get_texts() function defined in your MyApp class.

With these steps, you should be able to use the hot reload feature to see real-time modifications to your KivyMD app, and the function should be correctly bound to the button's on_release event.

Comment: I apreciatte your help, but that "python -m main" command didn't work. It opened my window, but I still can't see the changes in real-time. Thanks though.